# how to show 2 select options value in another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am have been searched too much on net but nothing found.
I have 2 select options tag.
I want to show option value in the input tag by multiplying option tag value whatever it is.
and selecting 2nd option tag I want to assign 2nd option tag value to 1st option tag value.
and I also want to multiply that values as the 1st options value have before. 
how to do this?

here is my code.
My 1st options tag.

```
<select name="" id="test">

        <option selected="" value="0" disabled='disabled'>Select Duration</option>
        <option value="1">1/month</option>
        <option value="2">2/month</option>
        <option value="3">3/month</option>
        <option value="6">6/month</option>
        <option value="12">12/month</option>

    </select>
    <input type="text" data-val="9" id="price_value" style="border:1px solid #0a0; padding:1px 10px; color: #f90;" value="0" size="5"/><br>
```

Here is 2nd option tag.

```
<select id="plan">
  <option  value='Basic'>Basic</option>
  <option  value='Standard'>Standard</option>
  <option  value='Professional'>Professional</option>
  <option  value='Enterprice'>Enterprise</option>
</select>
```

here is JS.

```
$('#test').on('change',function(e){
    var input = $(this).next('input[type="text"]');
    var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    input.val( input.data('val') * parseInt(value) );
});


$('#plan').on('change',function(e) {
    var plan = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    var price_value = $('#price_value');

    if (plan == "Basic") {
        price_value.removeAttr('data-val');
        price_value.attr('data-val','9');
    }
    else if (plan == "Standard"){
        price_value.removeAttr('data-val');
        price_value.attr('data-val','19');
    }
    else if (plan == "Professional"){
        price_value.removeAttr('data-val');
        price_value.attr('data-val','29');
    }
    else if (plan == "Enterprice") {
        price_value.removeAttr('data-val');
        price_value.attr('data-val','59');
    }
});
```

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hsn0/q9Gdg/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes

1. Use `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).find('option:selected').val()` to fetch select value. or even better use `this.value`
2. use `.data()` to set value like `price_value.data('val', 9);` instead of `price_value.attr('data-val','9');`
3. No need to use `price_value.removeAttr('data-val');`

*Code*

```
$('#test').on('change',function(e){
    var input = $(this).next('input[type="text"]');
    var value = $(this).val(); //Or this.value
    input.val( input.data('val') * parseInt(value, 10) );
});


$('#plan').on('change',function(e) {
    var plan = $(this).val();
    var price_value = $('#price_value');

    if (plan == "Basic") {
        price_value.data('val',9);
    }
    else if (plan == "Standard"){
        price_value.data('val',19);
    }
    else if (plan == "Professional"){
        price_value.data('val',29);2
    }
    else if (plan == "Enterprice") {
        price_value.data('val',59);
    }
    $('#test').trigger('change'); //Trigger $('#test') change event

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FVnwL/)

Comment: This shouldn't show alert msg instead. just change the values of 1st option tags

Comment: @Mr.beginner, Thats for demo do what you want.

Comment: Yeah , :) now thats working fine and great job. :D :) thanks too much and many many.

Comment: Now can I save `price_val` value into php $_POST variable and then save into database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56514/discussion-between-satpal-and-mr-beginner).

Answer (score 0):

This solution would work if you are okay with changing your HTML a bit:

```
<select id="plan">
  <option value='9'>Basic</option>
  <option value='19'>Standard</option>
  <option value='29'>Professional</option>
  <option value='59'>Enterprise</option>
</select>
```

Then simply use:

```
$('#test, #plan').on('change',function() {
    var valueOne = $('#test').val();
    var valueTwo = $('#plan').val();
    $('#price_value').val(parseInt(valueOne) * parseInt(valueTwo));
});
```

That's all!